# how do you workaround this inconsistency between IE, Firefox and Chrome

Tags: html, css, margin

i have a background image on a webpage and i am placing an image in my body to line up over the image:

here is my css:

**Background:**

```
body {
 font: 12px tahoma, Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
 line-height: 1.5em;
 margin: 0px;
 padding: 0px;
 color: #241a10;
 background:#c9e4ec url(/Content/images/myImage.gif);
}
```

**Image:**

```
#leftSideContainer {
    position:relative;
    margin-top:-47px;
    width:147px;
    height:93px;
    background:url(/Content/Images/image2.gif);
}
```

In IE7 and Chrome, it looks perfect and lines up exact:
[image]

But in IE8 and Firefox, the image shows a little lower down compared to the background image:
[image]

If it was just an old version of IE that was broken i wouldn't care but in this case firefox is broken as well.

i tried playing with the:

```
 margin-top: -47px;
```

but if i move it higher to get it to line up in firefox, it them obviously looks misaligned for the other browsers.

any suggestions for what might be causing this discrepancy.?

Comment: Have you specified a DOCTYPE?

Comment: Fix it for FF and Chrome and use conditional comments to target IE.

Comment: You must be doing *something* wrong to be getting those results. Chrome and Firefox should be matching each other with mundane CSS like that. Can you recreate the problem on [JS Bin](http://jsbin.com/)?

Comment: @Jawad - FF and Chrome are not consistent so i can't figure out any css to put that would work in both FF and Chrome

Comment: @thirtydot - what do you mean by "something wrong"?  what should i be looking at which may be off ?

Comment: @Briedis - i tried both <!DOCTYPE html> and  <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">

Comment: @ooo: I don't know what the "something" is, that's why I want to see your complete relevant code.

Comment: @ooo: Real way to investigate is if we had the live code with the images working. As suggested by @thirtydot: If you can make a live example, it would help us a lot.

Comment: @Jawad: EEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEKKKKKKKK!! (I have a general constitutional objection to using more than one exclamation mark per sentence as bad grammar, but that merited *two*.)  [I refer your first comment.]

Comment: @Chris Morgan: I don't get you. Have below average IQ. EYC (Express yourself clearly)

Comment: @Jawad: suggesting fixing it for Firefox and Chrome and using *conditional comments* for IE as first advice seems to be a very bad idea - after seeing the code, it is possible that it could end up being the best way to do it, but it doesn't even look to me like a case where conditional comments will be wanted. They might help to solve the symptoms, but it's ever so much better to solve the problem than the symptoms.

Comment: @Chris Morgan: You are right. +1 (lack of complete code from the OP)

Comment: @ooo: Please check if the size of the html/body elements the same in all browsers. If they differ, that might be the cause!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

CSS reset is your friend

http://meyerweb.com/eric/tools/css/reset/

> The goal of a reset stylesheet is to reduce browser inconsistencies in things like default line heights, margins and font sizes of headings, and so on.

Comment: It *might* be this, but it seems unlikely based on the browsers that match each other and the browsers that don't.

Comment: My thought process was that there may be other css properties applied to these elements further up the stylesheet (looks like that may be the case). If so, the outcome of Chrome vs Firefox might not be the same as they use webkit and gecko rendering engines, respectively.

Comment: @adlawson - this didn't seem to do anything

Comment: Well, if you include the reset css _before_ your current css, and you have provided us with literally _all_ of your styles, then there's something wrong.